# Async mongodb find within loop finishing early before returning all data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am using the [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) utility module to return items from a Mongodb database. I want to do it asynchronously. I am having problems when trying to return those items.

I want to fire the callback once ALL of the `User.find()'s` have been finished, right now the `async.each()` is terminating early, and only giving me one item from the database when it should be returning them all.

The code is below:

```
async.each(lessons, function(lesson, next) { // For each item in lesson array
    if (_.isEmpty(lesson.lesson_grades) == true) { // Check if the grades array is empty
        return;
    } else {
        async.each(lesson.lesson_grades, function(grade, next) { // For each grade in grade array
            User.find({ // Find user from grade user_id
                _id: grade.user_id,
            }, '-salt -hashedPassword', function(err, user) {

                grade["name"] = user[0].name; // Add name
                grade["email"] = user[0].email; // Add email

                next(); // !! I think this is where the problem lies, it fires next() once the first item has been returned - so it doesn't get to the other items !!
            });
        }, function(err) {
            next(lessons);
        });
    }
}, function(lessons, err) {
    return res.json(200, lessons); // Return modified lessons (with name and email) to browser, currently only returns one but returns them all if a setTimeout() is added, making it a premature callback problem
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this correctly? Should I be keeping track of the iterations? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The convention followed by async is that a callback function takes two arguments: the error and the result, *in that order*. The distinction between error and result is important, because async finishes immediately if it receives an error. The part that says `function(err) { next(lessons); }` is wrong - async misinterprets `lessons` as an error because it's truthy. It should read:

```
function(err, result) {
    next(err, result);
}
```

Or in fact you could just replace the function with `next`.

Also, near the end `function(lessons, error)` should be `function(error)`.

Another thing to watch out for: You must make sure every callback is called once and once only. But if it runs the `if` block instead of the `else` block, `next` is never called; async will never finish. It won't block other code from running, but it will never reach `return res.json(200, lessons);`. (It may also leak memory, I'm not sure.)

One final thing: Returning the result inside the callback won't do anything. It sort of looks like you're trying to call all this asynchronous code from a synchronous function; this doesn't work. `res.json` will be called, but if it returns an value then maybe you wanted to use that value as an argument to another callback function from somewhere else. But I'd need more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer. I've made the changes that you suggested but I still have the same problem. Can you guide me as to how to rewrite it? I've been trying all day since you posted this answer. Thank you.

Comment: How are you getting output from this? Also, note my change to my answer - the function at the end should not have `lessons` as an argument at all (it should be a closure variable instead).